# Rails - include javascript tag with dynamic (per request) filename?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Inside of `assets/javascripts/locales`, I have a bunch of assets like:

```
en-GB.js.erb
en-CA.js.erb
```

And so on. The locale will obviously change per request, so I am trying to include a JS tag like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'locales/#{I18n.locale}.js' %>
```

However, I end up seeing this error:

```
The asset "locales/.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

So it would seem that the variable insertion isn't working correctly, although I am already using `I18n.locale` in other places in the same file.

How do I accomplish this? Although `locales/#{I18n.locale}.js` changes per request, the actual assets themselves are indeed static.

Answer (score 1):

String literals with singular quotes do not interpolate, and you get

```html
<script src="/javascripts/locales/.js#{I18n.locale}.js"></script>
```

with part after `#` treated as an url anchor part

try

```rb
javascript_include_tag "locales/#{I18n.locale}.js"
```